# Type mismatch using inject()-function from Koin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin

I'm using the dependency injection framework Koin in my app. The following line of code works perfectly in my MainActivity:

```
private val auth: FirebaseAuth by inject()
```

Unfortunately, the same line of code does not work in a custom BroadcastReceiver.
Android Studio marks the "inject()"-function red and tells me it is an unresolved reference (import of "org.koin.android.ext.android.inject" is marked as unused).

When I try to build it nevertheless, I got the following exception:

> Error:(14, 39) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates
>   is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public inline fun
>    ComponentCallbacks.inject(name: String = ...):
>   Lazy defined in org.koin.android.ext.android

How can I make the injection work in this class and why does it fail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `inject` method you use in Activities is defined [here](https://github.com/Ekito/koin/blob/master/android/koin-android/src/main/java/org/koin/android/ext/android/AndroidExt.kt#L61) like so:

```
/**
 * inject lazily given dependency for Android component
 * @param name - bean name / optional
 */
inline fun <reified T> ComponentCallbacks.inject(name: String = "") 
    = lazy { (StandAloneContext.koinContext as KoinContext).get<T>(name) }
```

So you can call it in classes that implement the [`ComponentCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks.html) interface - these would be application components, like Activities or Services.

If you wish to use Koin the same way in your BroadcastReceiver, you can define another `inject` extension on that class with the same implementation:

```
inline fun <reified T> BroadcastReceiver.inject(name: String = "") 
    = lazy { (StandAloneContext.koinContext as KoinContext).get<T>(name) }
```

Comment: This works well, but to be more generic I left out the Receiver completly, so that inject() can be used in everywhere

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable as well. I'm not sure why it's defined on `ComponentCallbacks` to begin with, since it doesn't make use of a `Context` or anything like that. I suppose it's only so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace with a new method that's usually used in specific classes only..

Comment: Take a look for this answer：https://stackoverflow.com/a/55675198/5643911

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I was trying to inject something in my viewmodel.
I was able to inject the same dependency in my Fragment and Activity classes but in my Viewmodels.

I didn't create a custom extension function. Instead, I changed my class to implement `KoinComponent` . And then it was able to recognize the extension of inject function.