# Koin how to inject outside of Android activity / appcompatactivity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, inversion-of-control, koin

**[Koin](https://github.com/Ekito/koin)** is a new, lightweight library for DI and can be used in Android as well as in standalone kotlin apps.

Usually you inject dependencies like this:

```
class SplashScreenActivity : Activity() {

    val sampleClass : SampleClass by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

with the `inject()` method.

But what about injecting stuff in places where Activity context is not available i.e. **outside of an Activity**?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same question

Answer (score 77):

There is the `KoinComponent` which comes to the rescue. In any class you can simply:

```
class SampleClass : KoinComponent {

    val a : A? by inject()
    val b : B? by inject()
}
```

Extending `KoinComponent` gives you access to `inject()` method.

Remember that usually it's enough to inject stuff the usual way:

```
class SampleClass(val a : A?, val b: B?)
```

Comment: are you sure that your A and B classes can have null values?

Comment: Hmm, I think that from the KISS perspective it is better to use constructor (not to over-engineer thing ;)) as an injection point in such cases. But it is interesting that we can extend `Koin component` to allow injection using Koin.

Comment: Are you saying we don't need `startKoin` in this case?

Comment: Be aware that KoinComponent should not be used if not strictly necessary: "The other thing I’ve seen around is the misuse of KoinComponent interface to extend service locator API. Be aware that as a Koin framework user, you shouldn’t need to use this interface. "  https://medium.com/koin-developers/whats-next-with-koin-2-2-3-0-releases-6c5464ae5e3d

Answer (score 25):

Koin provides a solution for this using the `KoinComponent` interface. For example, if you need to get some dependencies in your repository then you can simply implement the KoinComponent interface. It gives you access to various Koin features such as `get()` and `inject()`. Use KoinComponent only when you can't rewrite the constructor to accept dependencies as constructor parameters.

```
class MyRepository: Repository(), KoinComponent {
  private val myService by inject<MyService>()
}
```

**Constructor injection is better than this approach.**

For example, the same thing can be achieved by:

```
class MyRepository(private val service: MyService): Repository() {
    ...
}
```

And you can add the definition for instantiating this class in a koin module:

```
val serviceModule = module {
    ...

    factory { MyService() }
}
val repositoryModule = module {
    ...

    factory { MyRepository(get<MyService>()) }
}
```

Comment: Why is constructor injection better than that approach with KoinComponent?

Comment: The approach with KoinComponent is known as Field injection. Here are a few reasons why constructor injection is better:

1. Simpler: Your class only care about what dependencies it needs, not about who satisfies them.
2. More Robust: An instance of your class in a consistent state as soon as it is constructed, rather than after the field injection is complete.
3. Easier testing: Declaring dependencies in the constructor makes it easier to supply their mocks while testing.

Comment: @harold_admin 
nice answer, can you please explain what is "Repository()" that we extend/implement here?

Comment: @Hatzil It could be any base class. Honestly it doesn't really matter for the purpose of this example. I just wanted to illustrate that you can use Koin whether you have a base class or not.

Comment: Hey @harold_admin good answer, still have a question that how about if the "MyRepository" is a Manifest-declared broadcast receivers? I've solve this by using koin inject extension but maybe there is another solution?

Comment: @ininmm I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Is "MyRepository" a broadcast receiver, or does it depend on a broadcast receiver? In the first case, I don't think you can use constructor injection because BroadcastReceivers are instantiated by the system, leaving field injection as the only option.

Comment: Yes I mean that "MyRepository" is derived from a broadcast receiver. You absolutely right, using field injection is the only silver bullet.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to implement any interfaces then just take a look at how [`KoinComponent.inject()`](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/core/koin-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/koin/core/component/KoinComponent.kt#L56-L61) is implemented and do something similar yourself:

```
val foo by lazy { KoinPlatformTools.defaultContext().get().get<FooClass>() }
```

Comment: Especially useful if you want to access something that is configured by koin from the ApplicationClass itself :)

Comment: Can this be applied to within a Service, such as `FirebaseMessagingService`?